# I am having trouble when translating c to legv8

Tags: c++, assembly

```
long long int addsub (long long int a, long long int b) {
    if (a>=b)
        return a-b;
    else
        return a+b;
}
```

im trying to change the above c to legv8

i'm stuck after this doesn't work.

```
addsub:
    sub sp, sp, #16
    stur x0, [sp, #8]
    stur x1, [sp, #0]
    subs xzr, x0, x1
    b.ge L1
    ldur x1, [sp, #8]
    ldur x0, [sp, #0]
    sub x0, x1, x0
    b L2
L1:
    ldur x1, [sp, #8]
    ldur x0, [sp, #0]
    add x0, x1, x0
L2:
    add sp, sp, #16
    ret
    br x30
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could teach me what is currently wrong.
I am a new student to computers.
Thank you

Comment: okay on it right now

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? Please be more specific.

Comment: Did you start with `gcc -O0` output?  The function args arrive in registers, no need to store and reload them to the stack.